# Npm module not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm running an Angular app built with Grunt and using Bower and NPM.

I tried installing my npm module locally. The files are in the main app directory in `node_modules` folder.

The module docs ask me to load the module with `<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>`, but I get 404.

Am I missing something? Do I have to tell Grunt that I want these NPM modules?

Comment: it's not really possible to answer this without seeing your project, or at least having more information on how your project is organized. Are you sure that moment is installed in your node modules? What is your gruntfile doing? Where are you adding this script tag? If you have a public GitHub repo I'm happy to take a look

Comment: I'm sure it is installed and in `package.json`. I don't know if the node_modules should be compiled into `dist` folder. It's not there, but `bower_components` is. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @user841760 did you get a solution to this? I am working on a ReactJS project and facing the same issue. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information on what your app is built with? If node serves your app, you need to make the directory you link to public. Assuming you're using express, this would look something like this in your `app.js` file:

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/moment/moment.js'));
```

Edit: 
Or if you just want to make it work, try to load moment.js from CDN like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

[Link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/) to moment on CDN

Comment: I used this generator [link](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)

Comment: I do not use express. Is there a way that would let me use npm modules without needing to add on another framework?

Comment: You might want to look at [this file](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/route/USAGE) and add path to `node_modules/moment/moment.js`

Comment: though this seems like just a way to add a simple route with a controller that's hooked to the main app js file

Comment: I really don't know much about angular, so might be the wrong place to look for it. However, I suspect that somewhere you have to instruct your app to treat the moments file in the node_modules as static resource so it can load it from the html. If you jsut want to make it work, you could also try to change the script source to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js`. maybe that's the easiest solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, npm is the package manager for all the javaScript frameworks such as Nodejs, angularjs etc. npm should be installed globally in the machine.You can install it from https://nodejs.org/en/ .

Next,you need check for the **package.json** file in your project.

If there is a **package.json** **already existing** in your project folder, then from command line you need to go to your project folder and type **npm start**.

If **package.json file does not exist**, then in the command line type **npm  init**,then there will be a **package.json**file created in your project folder.Then edit the package.json . and add the node packages into the **package.json** as similar way to this

```
{
  "name": "shoppingkart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www" //If you have any scripts.
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^4.9.0",  // here you should have all your node_modules listed
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "stripe": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

if you are not able to add the dependencies  to  json file, there is also another way to do it.
 just go to your project directory in the command line and type

```
npm install --save grunt // And you need to do for all the node_modules, by replacing the **grunt**.
```

Automatically the dependency will be added to your package.json file.

Comment: I do have a `package.json`. I'm adding all of the dependencies with `--save` flag. It's not that.

Comment: Are you including the modules in the top of the .js files like require('mongoose') or a similar kind of things. Can you share your package.json file. Have you started  the server in the app.js.

Comment: yes, I have run `grunt serve`. I've got this added in `package.json` after installing the module with `--save` flag: `"dependencies": {
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.1.3"
  }` But I did not say require('module'). I did use `<script src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>`

Comment: note that `moment.js` is a dependency of the said npm module

Comment: I cannot use `require` in js as it's not defined. adding the dependency to module dependencies in the angular module will give me more errors, namely `$injector.modulerr` error which complains the module is not there

Comment: What I do not know is if the app is actually served from `dist` and looking for the `node_modules` in `dist` folder. I would check it by trial and error if I could find out how to make the node modules rendered into `dist` and I guess (it's just my guess) I'd need to tell grunt to do that. I just don't know how

Comment: Is your html elements getting displayed?? If it is not then the local server is not working. If it is the problem of rendering the modules , still the html elements gets displayed on the webpage.I cannot see moment dependencies in the json file. Try typing the following command npm install moment --save. and then refresh

Comment: If you are only constrained to front end , then try the following code                    <script data-require="moment.js@2.8.3" data-semver="2.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: For more reference you can visit this website [link]http://onehungrymind.com/build-custom-filter-angularjs-moment-js/

Comment: Everything else is getting displayed ok. it's just this one isolated issue I'm facing

Comment: Then you must tell me the exact error that is getting displayed on the page. Only then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed your npm packages locally then your node_modules folder should found at the root of your project.

If you installed all your packages globally you may not see an npm_modules folder in your project.

To see where your global modules are located you can run

```
npm list -g
```

Comment: it's installed locally and the npm folder is at root, as it should be. I think I should be able to refer it from root, but I keep getting 404

Comment: ah, I see, `npm list` shows `npm ERR! extraneous` for the module

Comment: ok, this is because I've stashed the changes. I installed the module again with `--save` flag but it still throws a 404

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue just install the package globally and save at the end.

Like:

`npm install -g <package> --save`

Even the above doesn't work then use `-f / --force` at the end to force install.